# MYSQL Query Doesn't Work?

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

Hello i am trying to insert data into some colums but it wont work. Can someone help?

I have this

```
<form  action="member.php?id=<?php echo $data["id"];?>" method="post" style="display:inline-block; font-size:14px">

<input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" name="add"  />

</form>
```

And then:

```
if(isset($_POST["add"])){
$reciver = $data["username"];
$sender = $_SESSION['name'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO friend-request(reciver, sender, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$query->bindValue(1, $reciver);
$query->bindValue(2, $sender);
$query->bindValue(3, time());
$query->execute();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can a MySQL table name have a hyphen without the name being escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timestamp` is a reserved word in MySQL. You'll have to escape with backticks:

```
INSERT ... ,`timestamp`) ...
            ^--       ^--
```

You don't check the return value of the `->execute()` call, so you'd never see mysql trying to tell you the query failed. **NEVER** assume a query has succeeded. **ALWAYS** check for errors. Right now your code is the equivalent of sticking fingers in your ears and going "lalalala can't hear you".

Answer (score 0):

I would say to write something like this instead:

```
$reciver = $_POST["username"];
```

Careful to SQL Injection when you insert data into your database.

And make sure you have the username input field inside your form